# Проблема с ссылками urls.py django

Tags: python, django

Текст ошибки -

```
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\phoenix\phoeniximportbd\import\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    path('', index),
NameError: name 'index' is not defined
```

urls.py в приложении -

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
]
```

в ссылках корня проекта

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('import/', include('import.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция `index` не импортирована в модуле `urls.py`
Предположу, что она в модуле views.
Тогда

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]
```